# How to remove colon(:) by group and backwards reference

Tags: regex, group-by, reference, back

I have simple text like `Cancelled Tx Time 10:07` and regex to  retrieve - just `10 07` (space is ok) and I have following regex with back reference

```
/(Cancelled Tx Time\s(?<ValueCD>.*))(?<CF>\k<ValueCD>.*[^:])/gm
```

and what i get is `10:07`

Any feedback what I am doing wrong?

Comment: What regex tool or language are you using here?

Comment: Why are you using `\k` in your regex?

Comment: based on Microsoft info https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/backreference-constructs-in-regular-expressions#what-backreferences-match

Comment: using https://regex101.com/

Answer (score 1):

The regex you have is fine.

The colon is part of the match and of the group value that captures that string part, and you can remove it after you get a match.

You can use

```cs
Cancelled Tx Time\s+(.*)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tboHuZ/1).
Once you have a match, use something like `Replace(":", "")` on the Group 1 value.

Another way is to use a regex replace operation with

```cs
Cancelled Tx Time\s+(\d+):(\d+)
```

as regex and `$1 $2` (`\1 \2`) as the replacement pattern. See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tboHuZ/2).

The `(\d+):(\d+)` part captures two groups of digits into separate groups with IDs 1 and 2, and the backreferences in the replacement join the values together.

Comment: not sure where I am doing wrong - I want to be in one regex, so I tried  the following /Cancelled Tx Time\s+(\d+):(\d+)(?<a3>\1.*\2.*)/gm but errors out. I can certainly the two groups separate statement  and get the information and then concatenate.

Comment: @GeoV Use the regex I suggested. Do not use named capturing groups with backreferences.

Comment: how do I back reference to bring them togerther

Comment: Just as shown [here](https://regex101.com/r/tboHuZ/2). Also see [sample code](https://regex101.com/r/tboHuZ/2/codegen?language=javascript).